# Identify outputs from bus selector in matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to identify which signals are selected by a bus selector block in matlab. In essence I am working on a script that compresses multiple blocks into one single lookup table. In order to do this I need to identify the inputs to all the blocks yet if the input to one of the blocks is a mux of variables then I need to identify the signal after the de-mux (in this case a bus selector).

I have tried `get_param(*pathtoblock*,'dialogParameters')` yet the output

```
 OutputSignals: [1x1 struct]
 OutputAsBus:   [1x1 struct]
 InputSignals:  [1x1 struct]
```

Holds emtpy cells as shown below

[image: Output signals from bus sel block]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
>> get_param(block, 'OutputSignals')

ans = 
'data,limits,limits.lower_saturation_limit'
```

gives you a comma separated list of the names of the selected signals.  Is this what you need?